# .Net 5 project Docker COPY file is not found

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .Net 5 project called SaveGame with a `Dockerfile` generated automatically by Visual Studio. Checked many official tutorials and whatnot - the Dockerfile always looks the same.

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SaveGame.API/SaveGame.API.csproj", "SaveGame.API/"]
RUN dotnet restore "SaveGame.API/SaveGame.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SaveGame.API"
RUN dotnet build "SaveGame.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SaveGame.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SaveGame.API.dll"]
```

Here's the folder with the `Dockerfile`:
[image]

Here's the folder with the project file:
[image]

I try to build a Docker image with a command

`docker build -t savegame .`

Yet the `COPY` command fails giving me this

```
[+] Building 0.4s (9/17)
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 35B                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim                                      0.3s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim                                   0.3s
 => CANCELED [build 1/7] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim@sha256:1ab344109a790d555aa9d618edc012a  0.0s
 => => resolve mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim@sha256:1ab344109a790d555aa9d618edc012a2f88781f01238fd  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2.78kB                                                                                0.0s
 => CANCELED [base 1/2] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim@sha256:76b29928ab5b442469c89cc7eb5f6  0.0s
 => => resolve mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim@sha256:76b29928ab5b442469c89cc7eb5f6ef12d9e6e4139a  0.0s
 => CACHED [build 2/7] WORKDIR /src                                                                                0.0s
 => ERROR [build 3/7] COPY [SaveGame.API/SaveGame.API.csproj, SaveGame.API/]                                       0.0s
------
 > [build 3/7] COPY [SaveGame.API/SaveGame.API.csproj, SaveGame.API/]:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: failed to compute cache key: "/SaveGame.API/SaveGame.API.csproj" not found: not found
```

Why does it not find the file?

EDIT:

Running it on Github -> Azure WebApp (Linux) deploy job, I get kinda same thing

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim
 ---> 8eab6017c69e
Step 6/17 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in bbe55e12dd3a
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat src/SaveGame.API/SaveGame.API.csproj,: file does not exist
Removing intermediate container bbe55e12dd3a
 ---> 595dc1db2583
Step 7/17 : COPY src/SaveGame.API/SaveGame.API.csproj, SaveGame.API/
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: As you are running it on Windows machine, make sure the docker is running as Windows host and not Linux.

Comment: But when I try to deploy it through GitHub to Azure Web App - it fails in the same spot. Fixing that is more important than fixing it locally. And I'm not too sure where to start

Comment: For Azure, what is the OS of WebApp?

Comment: It's Linux. Not sure if Windows has a bigger price, so I decided to go with Linux

Comment: Do Linux docker files look different?

Comment: The docker files would be the same for both OSes. And you made the correct decision to go with Linux on WebApp as it is cheaper.

Comment: remove comma from `COPY src/SaveGame.API/SaveGame.API.csproj, SaveGame.API/`, leave just  `COPY src/SaveGame.API/SaveGame.API.csproj SaveGame.API/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WORKDIR` does not do what you expect it to do. It sets the current directory in the docker container. Use

```
COPY ["src/SaveGame.API/SaveGame.API.csproj", "SaveGame.API/"]
```

and it will work fine. Also, you will need to `cd` into the `SaveGame.API` before running `dotnet restore` if you don't have `.sln` file in the current directory.

Comment: Thank you, this actually worked. Thanks a lot!Even Pluralsight tutorials use the `WORKDIR` like this. So I thought this is the way to use it. Guess they don't run their own code.

Answer (score 0):

Because you run `docker build -t savegame .`. I believe that your current directory was `repos/SaveGame.API` and when docker run to the command `COPY ["SaveGame.API/SaveGame.API.csproj", "SaveGame.API/"]` there is no `SaveGame.API` directory in the current context to make a copy. It's nested under the `src` directory.

Edit that line to `COPY ["src/SaveGame.API/SaveGame.API.csproj", "SaveGame.API/"]`